# Using the Transition Constraint to rotate an object

Tags: animation, constraints

I'm trying to use the X global rotation of the central object in the screenshot to rotate the Y Local rotation of the object displaying it's local axis markers using the Transition Constraint.

This is for an animation - all four objects are substitutes for what will be ailerons in the real animation so I have set up these primitives to mimic the real objects for clarity.

I would like to create variations in timing etc in the final animation so a system like this negates further animations.

[image]
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about the *Transformation* constraint, here are the settings you need. Enable the *Extrapolate* option (if you don't want any limit to the rotation), *Target > World Space, Owner > Local Space, Map From* > enable *Rotation*, set an *X Max* and *Min, Map To > Rotation*, set the *Y Source* to X as the Y rotation axis will be determined by the X rotation of the cube, set a Y rotation *Min* and *Max*:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately whist the object does rotate n the Y axis it also rotates on the Z Axis and a Limit rotation constraint doesn't seem to work - grateful for any further suggestions if possible? Thank you.

Comment: @K.Cee Please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/